# I can't start mysqld.service -> status : Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress in centos 7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I've installed mysql 8 on centos 7

and when i want to start the mysqld service , it says :

```
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

and when i run systemctl status mysqld.service it says:

```
mysqld.service - MySQL Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-01-13 06:01:53 EST; 6min ago
Docs: man:mysqld(8)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
Process: 5532 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 5504 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5532 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"

Jan 13 06:01:48 server1.lifeandme.net systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jan 13 06:01:53 server1.lifeandme.net systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 13 06:01:53 server1.lifeandme.net systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Jan 13 06:01:53 server1.lifeandme.net systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Jan 13 06:01:53 server1.lifeandme.net systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

I also tried restart the service and cleaning log files under /var/lib/mysql , but no success

i did the following commands to install lamp on server (history related to lamp installation)

```
yum install httpd

systemctl start httpd.service

systemctl enable httpd.service

yum install mariadb-server mariadb

systemctl start mariadb

mysql_secure_installation

systemctl enable mariadb.service

yum install php php-mysql

systemctl restart httpd.service

yum remove php php-server

yum clean packages

yum install epel-release

yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

yum install yum-utils

yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72

yum install php72

yum remove mariadb mariadb-server

systemctl restart httpd.service

yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm

yum install mysql-community-server

systemctl enable mysqld

systemctl start mysqld =>  ran to error
```

Comment: You were upgrading from 5.7 to 8.0?  Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: @RickJames

yes , no i didn't use mysql_upgrade

i added the commands that i ran under my question

Comment: @RickJames
result after i did mysql_upgrade on terminal is as follow:
The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade                                                                                                              client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Rep                                                                                                             airing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.

Comment: 2.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE                                                                                                              option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to ru                                                                                                             n the server upgrade sequence on demand.
It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons.

Comment: 3.
In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --                                                                                                             upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.

Comment: (My bad-- not actually "mysql_upgrade".)  Do you have thousands of tables?  Are they huge?

Comment: @RickJames
no there isn't any database. I just installed centos 7 and lamp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

Clear the mysql data directory at `/var/lib/mysql` assuming that you have backups or you don't really need that data anymore.

Then `sudo service mysqld start`

Comment: The only solution that worked for me after hours of trials. Thank you.

Comment: And if i need the data?

Comment: then you can restore from backups after the upgrade